# How to properly structure Triggers and FK Cascade Update to coexist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are designing a schema so each "Main" table has an extra "Approval" table that holds up to one extra version of each object, which is the most recently approved version of that object (if it has been approved at all.) Some of these tables have sub-objects which hold Foreign Keys to the parent tables with an UPDATE CASCADE. Here is a minimal example, the tables appended with `_A` are the "Approval" tables and those without them are the "Main" tables:

```
Schedule
+----+----------+
| Id | Approved |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        0 |
+----+----------+


Schedule_A
+------------+
| ScheduleId |
+------------+
Foreign Key from ScheduleId to Schedule(Id)


ScheduleAssignment
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
| Id | Approved | ScheduleId | ChannelId |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        0 |          1 |         1 |
|  2 |        0 |          1 |         3 |
|  3 |        0 |          1 |         4 |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
Composite Foreign Key from (ScheduleId, Approved) to Schedule(Id, Approved) 
with CASCADE UPDATE


ScheduleAssignment_A
+----+------------+-----------+
| Id | ScheduleId | ChannelId |
+----+------------+-----------+
Foreign Key from ScheduleId to Schedule_A(Id)
```

We want to have Triggers on the Main tables (Schedule and ScheduleAssignment) so when an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` results in a record where the `Approved` column is `1`, the values get `MERGE`'d into the corresponding Approval table.

The idea here is an Advertising Associate could log in and create a pending Schedule with Assignments where records are inserted with `Approved` as `0`. Then an Admin logs into the system and approves the pending `Schedule`. This would update the record in the `Schedule` table to set `Approved` to `1`, which would do the following:

1. Set off the Trigger on the `Schedule` table to insert the newly approved record into the `Schedule_A` table
2. Via the CASCADE UPDATE in `ScheduleAssignment` on (`ScheduleId`, `Approved`), Update the `Approved` value in `ScheduleAssignment` for related records
3. As a result of (2), set off the Trigger on the `ScheduleAssignment` to insert the newly approved records into the `ScheduleAssignment_A` table.

The issue I'm having is that SQL SERVER is executing the CASCADE UPDATEs and Triggers in such an order where I'm getting the error:

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ScheduleAssignment_A_Schedule". The conflict occurred in database "Sandbox", table "dbo.Schedule_A", column 'Id'.`

Presumably the CASCADE UPDATE is updating the value and firing the trigger in the `ScheduleAssignment` table before setting off the Trigger in `Schedule`, So the values in `ScheduleAssignment_A` are having this conflict where they don't have a parent record in `Schedule_A`.

Is there any way I can setup these Triggers or Foreign Keys so that they resolve without running into this issue?

Edit: Add Sql Table Create Scripts

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Approved] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_ScheduleApproved] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [Approved] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Schedule_Approved]
ON [dbo].[Schedule]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Schedule_A (Id)
    SELECT Id
    FROM inserted
    WHERE Approved = 1
END

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule_A](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Schedule_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule_A]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Schedule_A_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule_A] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Schedule_A_Schedule]
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Approved] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChannelId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ScheduleAssignment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ScheduleAssignment_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleId], [Approved])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([Id], [Approved])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ScheduleAssignment_Schedule]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_ScheduleAssignment_Approved]
ON [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ScheduleAssignment_A (Id, ScheduleId, ChannelId)
    SELECT Id, ScheduleId, ChannelId
    FROM inserted
    WHERE Approved = 1
END

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment_A](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChannelId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ScheduleAssignment_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment_A]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ScheduleAssignment_A_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule_A] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment_A] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ScheduleAssignment_A_Schedule]
GO
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Schedule]
           ([Approved])
     VALUES
           (0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment]
           ([Approved], ScheduleId, ChannelId)
     VALUES
           (0, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 5)
           ,(0, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 6)
           ,(0, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 7)
           ,(0, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 8)
           ,(0, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 9)
```

From here, what I want to be able to do is come in an Approve this schedule (and its underlying assignments) like so:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Schedule]
SET [Approved] = 1
WHERE Approved = 0
GO
```

I want the result to be like so:

```
Schedule
+----+----------+
| Id | Approved |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
+----+----------+


Schedule_A
+------------+
| ScheduleId |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+


ScheduleAssignment
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
| Id | Approved | ScheduleId | ChannelId |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 |          1 |         5 |
|  2 |        1 |          1 |         6 |
|  3 |        1 |          1 |         7 |
|  4 |        1 |          1 |         8 |
|  5 |        1 |          1 |         9 |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+


ScheduleAssignment_A
+----+------------+-----------+
| Id | ScheduleId | ChannelId |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 |          1 |         5 |
|  2 |          1 |         6 |
|  3 |          1 |         7 |
|  4 |          1 |         8 |
|  5 |          1 |         9 |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

However I get the error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ScheduleAssignment_A_Schedule". The conflict occurred in database "Sandbox", table "dbo.Schedule_A", column 'Id'.
```

Comment: Something seems overly complicated in your design here. Can you post the table definition including foreign keys. I just can't quite follow this one.

Comment: @SeanLange Hey Sean, thanks for replying. Can you clarify what you want that wasn't included in the original post's tables? The Foreign Keys are specified underneath each table in case you missed them.

Comment: I meant post the create table statements, not a textual explanation that requires others to reassemble your ddl. Here is a good explanation. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Updated OP with create scripts for tables and triggers

Comment: Updated with Sample data, what I want to be able to do from the sample data, and the error I'm running into. I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Why do you have the `...A` tables? They just hold a copy of the information of the rows of the not `...A` tables where `Approved = 1`.

Comment: @stickybit They hold the latest approved data. When an insert or update on the Main table has Approved = 1, then the record(s) is inserted into the `...A` table. At this point the data is redundant, but then someone who doesn't have auto-approve privileges can come in and alter this `Schedule` and its `ScheduleAssignments`. So we keep track of these pending changes in the Main tables, while also keeping track of the most recently Approved version in the `..._A` tables.

Comment: I get it, but I must admit I think your solution is making life difficult. I’d also suggest not having the _A tables. Also the ScheduleAssignment does not need an Approved column because that can be derived from its relation to the Schedule table. One a schedule is Approved, then a person without auto-approve privilege can only create new unapproved Schedules. Then when this new Schedule is approved, a trigger deletes the previously approved schedule, essentially “replacing” it with a new version.

Comment: @JohnRees Agreed about the point on Approved columns in ScheduleAssignment. Could you elaborate on the suggestion of not using `_A` tables? If a user without auto-approve privileges modifies the approved Schedule, then it would be similar to creating a new unapproved Schedule. The caveat is if approved, the approved version of that Schedule should be removed. My thinking about advantages with `_A` tables is our two use cases for reading Schedules are reading only the approved versions, or reading the most recent version (either version if only one exists, or the pending version if both exist)

Comment: @JohnRees I think using `_A` tables is good for both of these use cases, and better than not using `_A` tables in the case of getting the most recent version. If both the approved and unapproved Schedule are in the same table, my understanding is the SELECT query to get the most recent versions of Schedules would require a JOIN with itself and/or a WHERE clause to check if there is a more recent version of each Schedule in the table.

Comment: @JohnRees If `_A` tables hold the approved versions and the Main tables only hold the most recent version, the entry in the Main table is always the most recent and thus a SELECT query could forgo these extra JOIN or WHERE. In the end I'm inexperienced with DBs, so I concede there are likely underlying issues with using these `_A` tables.

Comment: I understand your motivation to make your queries simple, but I think your approach may have other hidden downsides.  I've expanded my idea in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The approach using the approved _A tables initially seems attractive because it does allow simple querying for the obvious questions "What is approved" and "What is the latest".

However, it does not scale well as your database grows.  You will probably find that as additional relations are added to the database, you will often need to create one table linking to an approved table and another linking to an unapproved table.

This in turn will lead to writing **almost** identical queries for approved and unapproved entities. It will be like having two very similar databases: one for approved entities and one for unapproved, and keeping two things working in parallel is more than twice as hard as getting one working :-)

I realise that the above statements offer no facts, but are merely my experience when dealing with similar problems over the last few years.

My recommendation would be to treat "approval" more like a state, rather than different entities.  To cope with Schedules that have zero ScheduleAssignments, the Schedule needs an "EditInProgress" flag, and each ScheduleAssignment records whether it is Approved.

So the Schedule and ScheduleAssignment tables would be

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EditInProgress] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [Id] ASC )
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Approved] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChannelId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ScheduleAssignment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [Id] ASC )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ScheduleAssignment_Schedule] 
FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([Id])
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_ScheduleAssignment_1] ON [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment]
(
    [ScheduleId] ASC,
    [Approved] ASC,
    [ChannelId] ASC
)
GO
```

Initial data load looks like this

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Schedule] ([Id],[EditInProgress]) 
VALUES   (1,0) -- Schedule 1 is not being edited
        ,(2,1) -- Schedule 2 is being edited

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment] ([Approved], ScheduleId, ChannelId)
VALUES   (1, 1, 101) -- Schedule 1 has two approved assignments
        ,(1, 1, 102)
        ,(0, 2, 201) -- Schedule 2 has two unapproved assignments
        ,(0, 2, 202)
```

Performing an edit on a Schedule looks like

```sql
declare @CurrentScheduleId int = 1;

update dbo.Schedule set EditInProgress = 1 where Id = @CurrentScheduleId;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment] ([Approved], ScheduleId, ChannelId)
VALUES   (0, @CurrentScheduleId, 105) 
        ,(0, @CurrentScheduleId, 106)
        ,(0, @CurrentScheduleId, 107)
```

Approving a Schedule would be

```sql
declare @CurrentScheduleId int = 1;

if exists (select * from dbo.Schedule where Id = @CurrentScheduleId and EditInProgress = 1) begin

    update dbo.Schedule 
    set EditInProgress = 0 
    where Id = @CurrentScheduleId;

    delete dbo.ScheduleAssignment 
    where ScheduleId = @CurrentScheduleId and Approved = 1;

    update dbo.ScheduleAssignment 
    set Approved = 1 
    where ScheduleId = @CurrentScheduleId;
end
else begin
    raiserror (N'Approval denied for Schedule %d because EditInProgress <> 1',11,0,@CurrentScheduleId)
end;
```

Selecting Approved and Latest assignments would be:

```sql
select 'Approved' as ApprovedQuery, * 
from [dbo].[Schedule]
join [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment] on ScheduleAssignment.ScheduleId = Schedule.Id
where ScheduleAssignment.Approved = 1
order by 2,3,4
GO

select 'Latest' as LatestQuery, * 
from [dbo].[Schedule]
join [dbo].[ScheduleAssignment] on ScheduleAssignment.ScheduleId = Schedule.Id
where [Schedule].EditInProgress = 0 and ScheduleAssignment.Approved = 1 
   or [Schedule].EditInProgress = 1 and ScheduleAssignment.Approved = 0
order by 2,3,4
GO
```

This is all available as a SQL fiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ac135/1

I don't claim that the above is a perfect fit for your question, but I hope it is an avenue worth exploring to avoid an excess of tables.

I would also not recommend using triggers unless absolutely necessary.  They have their place, but they are incredibly annoying to maintain as they are often overlooked when trying to debug existing problems and also when adding new functionality.

Comment: Looks great. I have a question about extending the design to other table structures. Say `Schedule` now contained columns holding business information, `Name`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`. This is information can be edited by non-reviewers similar to the rest of `Schedule`, and requires approval. In this case, should a separate table be made to hold this business information that has a one-to-one relation with `Schedule` and contains an `Approved` column?

I filled in a SQL fiddle's schema to show what I mean http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84300

Comment: @Imbajoe It's always interesting when new requirements make me question the quality of my design.  What you suggest with a one-to-one relation between `ScheduleConfiguration` and `Schedule` would work, but it does give me a bad feeling that this approach is not scaling well either.  Each additional table is requiring an `Approved` column, so this concept is polluting the whole schema design.  I need a little time to think about this, and maybe rework my approach. If you're under time pressure, I'm not going to be able to help, but otherwise I'll post in a few days.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind it, I would appreciate any further help. And thanks for your contributions up to this point. There are parts of our system which don't require going through approvals so I've plenty of work in the mean time.